# file url to data uri convertion

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting file url from server through http.post request. I need to convert image to base64 string for database storage. I got solution using angular for ionic 2+ application

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, outputFormat){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
        img.onload = function(){
            let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('CANVAS'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            dataURL;
            canvas.height = this.height;
            canvas.width = this.width;
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
            //callback(dataURL);
            canvas = null;
            resolve(dataURL); 
        };
        img.src = url;
    });
}
```

and call using:

```
this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(someUrl, "image/jpeg")
.then( base64Img => {
   //do whatever you need here, with the base64 data
})
```

so i need to covert in using angularjs for ionic equivalent code..

Comment: Other than a possible typescript type if you aren't using typescript...what is there to convert?

Comment: this function using angular but this code need to be converted angularjs code

Comment: What is shown has nothing to do with angular. Promise, Image and canvas api's are all available in the browser. If you aren't using typescript just remove `<HTMLCanvasElement>`

Comment: let img = new Image();  equivalent code in angularjs

Comment: That is native javascript that creates a `<img>` element

Comment: tnx @charlietfl another help plz. showing error in  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0); Here this showing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162781/discussion-between-utpaul-and-charlietfl).